# Batch Process not inserted to the table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have following tables that used to store purchase & issue of items.

## store_update_stock Table

```
+-----------------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+--------+
| update_stock_id | supplier | user order_status | transfer_status | status |
+-----------------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+--------+
```

## store_update_stock_details Table

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+--------+
| update+stock_details_id | update_stock_id | item | qty | unit_price | status |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+--------+
```

02) I used Codeigniter for the project and files as follows :

## Controller

```
public function verifyItemReqFromHD()       
    {
        $this->checkPermissions('edit', 'issueApprovedItem');
        $bc = array(array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Item Request From HD'));
        $meta = array('page_title' => 'Item Request From HD', 'bc' => $bc);      
        $this->data['products'] = $this->Item_model->getProducts();     

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

            $count = count($this->input->post('item'));
            $items = $this->input->post('item');
            $qts = $this->input->post('qty'); 
            $up = $this->input->post('unit_price');         
            $total = 0;
            for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
                $details[$x]['update_stock_id'] = null;
                $details[$x]['item'] = $items[$x];
                $details[$x]['qty'] = $qts[$x]; 
                $details[$x]['unit_price'] = $up[$x];               
                $details[$x]['status'] = 1;               
            }

            $stock = array(             
                'supplier' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),              
                'user' => ucfirst($this->session->userdata('name')),
                'order_status' => 'verifyIssue',
                'transfer_status' => 'Verified',
                'status' => '1'
            );
            if ($this->Item_model->addItemReqFromHD($stock, $details)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Sent Your Request..!!');
                redirect('item/verifyItemReqFromHD');
            }

        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
            $this->render('item/viewItemtoIssued', $meta, $this->data);
        }
    }
```

## Model

```
function addItemReqFromHD($data,$details)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        if ($this->db->insert('store_update_stock', $data)) {
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            foreach ($details as $detail) {
                $detail['update_stock_id'] = $id;
                $this->db->insert('store_update_stock_details', $detail);
            }
        }
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === true) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;        

    }
```

## View

```
<?php
if(!empty($issueData)){
    $common=$issueData[0];
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("change", "#item", function () {

        $.ajax({
            'url': '<?=site_url("item/isExistProduct/?q=")?>' + $('#item').val(),
            'method': 'GET',
            'success': function (data) {


                var jData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jData.status == true) {

                jData.data.forEach(data => {
                    $('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
                        '<td ><span id="product" >' + data.item_name + '</span>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="item[]" name="item[]" value="' + data.item_id + '">' +
                        '</td>' +                       
                        '<td class="text-center">' + data.qty + '</td>' +                       
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right"  disabled id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + data.up+ '"></td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + data.qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +   
                        '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                    })
                }

            },
            'error': function () {

            }
        });


    });

    $(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

    var old_row_qty;
    $(document).on("focus", '.rquantity', function () {
        old_row_qty = $(this).val();
    }).on("change", '.rquantity', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var issue_q = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var available_q = parseFloat($(this).data('qty-bal'));

        if (issue_q > available_q) {
            console.log("ssss");
            $(row).addClass('danger');
            $('#add_sale').attr('disabled', true);
            alert("Can not proceed your request ..!!. Issue quantity is higher than the available quantity..");
        } else {
            console.log("remove");
            $(row).removeClass('danger');
            $('#add_sale').attr('disabled', false);

        }

    });
</script>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="invoice">
    <!-- title row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>


    <!-- Table row -->
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2%">
        <div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr class="" style="background-color: #33ff99 !important;">
                    <th>Item</th>                   
                    <th class="text-right">Requested Qty</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Approved Qty</th>        
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php

                if (!empty($issueData)) {
                    foreach ($issueData as $rows){

                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 40%"><?=$rows->item_name?></td>                           
                            <td style="width: 15%" class="text-right"><?=$rows->r_qty+0?></td>
                            <td style="width: 15%" class="text-right"><?=$rows->ap_qty+0?></td>                          
                        </tr>
                        <?php

                    }
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>


        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

   <form action="<?= site_url('item/verifyItemReqFromHD') ?>" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group"><label>Select Item</label>
                            <select name="item" id="item" class="form-control select2" required>
                                <option value="">Select Item</option>
                                <?php
                                if (!empty($products)) {
                                    foreach ($products as $row) {

                                        ?>

                                        <option value="<?= $row->item_id ?>"><?= $row->item_name ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }

                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="control-group table-group">
                            <label class="table-label">Issue Items *</label>

                            <div class="controls table-controls">
                                <table id="request_table"
                                       class="table items table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr class="" style="background-color: #ff66a3 !important;">
                                        <th class="col-md-5">Item Name</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Available Qty</th>                                        
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Unit Price</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Issuing Qty</th>

                                        </th>
                                        <th class="col-md-2" style="width: 30px !important; text-align: center;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                    <tr id="tfoot" class="tfoot active">
                                        <th colspan="2">Total</th>
                                        <th class="text-right"></th>
                                        <th class="text-center">0</th>

                                        <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"
                                                                   style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" id="add_sale" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Issue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </form>   
</section>
```

## Desired Output

03) Then I need to insert data to the both tables using above codes.

When press "Issue" button in the view the relevant values didn't insert to the tables. What can be going wrong ? Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
$this->db->trans_commit()

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @ Jahan zeb. To where $this->db->trans_commit()  ?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following validation to the controller.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item', 'Item', 'required');
```

And also changed the following line in my view.

```
'<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + data.item_id + '">' +
```

Solved the problem .....